# Getting Unauthorized Error 401 When I Call API Secure Endpoint with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm setting up a spring boot + keycloak project. I am able to generate the token by calling the keycloak endpoint. When I call an api from my application I get the error 401 Unauthorized Error. However I am passing "Bearer generated token".

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products") public List<String> getProducts(){
      return productService.getProducts(); }
```

KeycloakConfiguration:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate(){
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/products*").hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();

    }

}
```

Properties:

```
  server.port=8090 
  keycloak.enabled=true
  keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
  keycloak.realm=chamae-api 
  keycloak.resource=login-app
  keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

I would just like to access the api "products" by passing the generated Bearer token

Comment: have assigned your login user with role "user"

Comment: @ravthiru Yes, the user who generated the token is marked on the role mappings tab with a role user

Comment: Why don't you use springboot adapter , see this example https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-springboot-rest

Comment: you need RPT token to get access not just access token https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_obtaining_permissions